# jquery attribute selector [checked] no longer works as of 1.9

Tags: jquery, selector

I just ported some javascript code that was using jQuery 1.6.4 to v2.2.3.  I was surprised to see some code stop working.  I know about the attr verus prop debate, but this is regarding a attribute selector that stopped working. Basically I look to see how many checkboxes in a group are selected and I saw I was always getting 0.  The selector used to be something like

```
$('input:checkbox[checked]').length;
```

but I had to change it to

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').length;
```

Here is a jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8e2xbvqu/).  Click on the Javascript settings link to change from jQuery < 1.9 to one >= 1.9 and you'll see the results in the table change when you check the box.

Is this a bug with jQuery?  Was I using the attribute selector incorrectly?  Note, the jsfiddle example also shows that checking for an attribute value (e.g. "true" or "checked") is also not working.

This was checked with Chrome and IE so I don't think its a browser issue.

thanks

Comment: You can't Just upgrade one major version and expect everything to work smoothly. Take a look at jquery changelogs and migrate guide. Also, look about "semver" on google.